# Garage door opener get stuck sometimes

Tags: garage-door-opener

My garage door opener get stuck sometimes, it gives the sound it is going to close the garage door then it rolls back a little then stops.

Another push to the remote and same thing happens, it tries to move forward then backward a little then stops.

I'm not sure, should I clean the roller chain (what to use to clean it?), replace it, or does the problem in the opener engine, need to be replaced?

When I try to disconnect the door from the latch and close it manually, the problem is still there - it moves forward a little then backward then stops even though door is not connected.

Comment: Are the rollers binding at all in the rails?

Comment: Did you realize it is possible to operate doors by hand?  They are counter balanced so they should roll easily with 1 hand.  I open big 12x14' semitrailer doors that way when they're tuned up properly.  With the door closed, you can un-pin the automatic opener and try rolling the door by hand.  How does it roll?

Comment: Does this happen all the time or just occasionally? If so, is there maybe a mild obstruction in the guide rail that it is sometimes able to pass, sometimes not?

Comment: A video of the issue could help the rest of us identify it!

Comment: Since this happens occasionally _and_ it happens when trying to close it by hand (without the opener), it sounds like there is an obstruction in the rails or that the wheels or hinges may need to be greased. When it opens/closes _by hand_, does it do so easily or do you really have to push to make it move? If it doesn't open by hand easily, then the springs aren't set right and your best bet may be a professional adjustment. Garage door springs can kill you if you're not careful.

Comment: There is a photo eye across the door near the bottom. If that is obstructed it will do exactly what you are describing. I have mine serviced every five years and have everything cleaned and lubricated,  The only failure I had was when it was hit with a car, and I cannot blame that on the door.